# Android CoordinatorLayout placing Layout beneath others

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-coordinatorlayout

I have a `CoordinatorLayout` and I want a `FrameLayout` be underneath all the other `Layouts and widgets`. I have tried using `android:layout_below/above` and `app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"`, but none of them go above the `FrameLayout` whose `android:id="@+id/container"`.

I think the easiest way would be to put the `FrameLayout` beneath others. For example in javascript there is `Z-index`.

I am not sure but maybe it is also important to note that the `FrameLayout` will containt preview from the camera and `AppBarLayout` is on top of it even if I dont change anything there.

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:ignore="ExtraText">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/songTitle"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/container"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.025">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/backToSongList"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Song List" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/gameBoard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="132dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/songTitle"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/app_bar"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView
            android:id="@+id/graph"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/playRecord"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"

        android:layout_above="@id/container"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/star_big_on"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pitchText"
        android:layout_width="113dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/playRecord"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.724"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/playRecord"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/songTitle"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/songTitle"
        android:layout_width="380dp"
        android:layout_height="61dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/container"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/playRecord"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="391dp"
        android:layout_height="569dp"
        android:background="#000"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        tools:context="com.example.richard.smarttabs.SongPlayer" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Since I am learning, all comments on my style are also welcome!

**EDIT: I got it to work and the code looks like this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:ignore="ExtraText">


    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#000"
        tools:context="com.example.richard.smarttabs.SongPlayer" />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/backToSongList"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Song List" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/gameBoard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="138dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="#c1c1c1"
        android:alpha="0.4">

        <com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView
            android:id="@+id/graph"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/playRecord"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="21dp"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:alpha="0.5"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pitchText"
        android:layout_width="84dp"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="21dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/songTitle"
        android:layout_width="380dp"
        android:layout_height="77dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="120dp"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:background="#918c8c"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#b3b3"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I would suggest you using LinearLayout  inside Relative Layout instead.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   >

 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/songTitle"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/container"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.025">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/backToSongList"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Song List" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/gameBoard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="132dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/songTitle"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/app_bar"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView
            android:id="@+id/graph"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/playRecord"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"

        android:layout_above="@id/container"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/star_big_on"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pitchText"
        android:layout_width="113dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/playRecord"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.724"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/playRecord"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/songTitle"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/songTitle"
        android:layout_width="380dp"
        android:layout_height="61dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/container"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/playRecord"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="391dp"
        android:layout_height="569dp"
        android:background="#000"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        tools:context="com.example.richard.smarttabs.SongPlayer" />

       </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Please note: I have simply copied your xml, so some of the attributes you might have to change or remove. Android Studio can help in that

Comment: I tried it, changed everything so it would fit but the layout was still on top.

Comment: would you be able to attach a screenshot? Thanks

Comment: Cool, glad to know